# Merge two pictures in Excel. Error 1004, cannot insert data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm flying a drone, and would like to be able to point out things on a picture by adding an arrow with a single click. By clicking an arrow will be added and the end will point towards the closest corner. When clicking on a picture the macro draw arrow will be run. The code is able to run (most times), however I do have some problems.

[Picture of the final result, where the tip of the arrow is inserted at the mouse location when clicked at the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WjMY.jpg)

- The first one is that for embed the arrow in the original picture I select both pictures and do a copy paste operation. Then I delete the old picture and the arrow. There is probably a smarter way of doing it. Sometimes in the operation of pasting the picture in to a cell a error happens : Error 1004, Microsoft Excel cannot insert the data. 
  The problem occurs in the Sub SaveFigure where a picture is moved to a chart and is saved external and in the main sub drawArrow at the line "ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select".
- Another problem that I have, is I have big difficulties to avoid using .select. I have tried to set the combined picture = an object. I do not know how to insert it in the sheet agian. Do anyone know how to do that?

I have inserted the whole code below, if other are facing the same problem of embed figures in picture.

Edit: I had forgot some data types and functions. They are in the code now.

```
Type RECT
    Left As Long: Top As Long: Right As Long: Bottom As Long
End Type
Type POINTAPI
    Xcoord As Long: Ycoord As Long
End Type

Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (Point As POINTAPI) As Long
Sub drawArrow()
Dim PictureName As String, ArrowName As String, TempName As String
Dim CellLoacation As Collection
Dim Pointlocation As Collection
Dim CellX As Integer, CellY As Integer, CompensateX As Integer, CompensateY As Integer
Dim PicX As Single, PicY As Single, MouseX As Single, MouseY As Single, PicHeight As Single, PicWidth As Single
Dim Arrow As Shape, EditedShape As Shape
Dim strImageName As String

PictureName = shapename
Set CellLoacation = PictureLocatedInCell(PictureName)
CellX = CellLoacation.Item(1) ' the cells x position
CellY = CellLoacation.Item(2) ' the cells y position
PicX = CellLoacation.Item(3) ' the pictures x position
PicY = CellLoacation.Item(4) ' the pictures x position
PicWidth = CellLoacation.Item(5) 'width of the picture
PicHeight = CellLoacation.Item(6) 'Height of the picture
Set Pointlocation = SH03G13(PictureName, CellX, CellY)
MouseX = Pointlocation.Item(1) 'Where the mouse is located at x in pt
MouseY = Pointlocation.Item(2) 'Where the mouse is located at y in pt

CompensateX = ArrowXEndPoint(MouseX, PicWidth) ' Taking zoom into account
CompensateY = ArrowYEndPoint(MouseY, PicHeight) ' Taking zoom into account
Set Arrow = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, PicX + CompensateX, PicY + CompensateY, PicX + MouseX, PicY + MouseY + Round(CellX / 7, 0))
ArrowName = Arrow.name
Arrow.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
Arrow.ShapeStyle = msoLineStylePreset1
With Arrow.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
End With
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(ArrowName, _
PictureName)).Select ' select both arrow and picture
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture 
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select ' insert picture in sheet - this is where it fails
ActiveSheet.Pictures.OnAction = "drawArrow" ' enable macro
TempName = Selection.name
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(ArrowName, _
PictureName)).Select
Selection.Delete' delete old picture and arrow

ActiveSheet.Shapes(TempName).Left = Sheets("Input").Cells(CellX, CellY).Left
ActiveSheet.Shapes(TempName).Top = Sheets("Input").Cells(CellX, CellY).Top

SaveFigure TempName, CellX

End Sub

Sub SaveFigure(TempName, CellX) 'gemmer figuren i en undermappe til hovedmappen
Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    S_PATH = Sheets("Data").Range("E1").Value
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")

            .Activate

            Set chtObj = .ChartObjects.add(0, 0, .Shapes(TempName).Width, .Shapes(TempName).Height)
            chtObj.name = "TemporaryPictureChart"
            'ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(TempName)).Copy
            ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(TempName)).Select
            Selection.Copy

            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("TemporaryPictureChart").Activate
            ActiveChart.Paste
            ActiveChart.Export fileName:=S_PATH & "\arrowPics\" & Sheets("Input").Cells(CellX, 1), FilterName:="jpg"

            chtObj.Delete

        End With
End Sub

Function ArrowYEndPoint(MouseY, PicHeight) As Integer ' where to set the end point of the arrow
If (MouseY < PicHeight / 2) Then
    If (MouseY < 100) Then
        ArrowYEndPoint = 0
    Else
        ArrowYEndPoint = MouseY - 75
    End If
ElseIf (MouseY > PicHeight / 2) Then
    If (MouseY > PicHeight - 100) Then
        ArrowYEndPoint = PicHeight
    Else
        ArrowYEndPoint = MouseY + 75
    End If
End If
End Function

Function ArrowXEndPoint(MouseX, PicWidth) As Integer where to set the end point of the arrow
If (MouseX < PicWidth / 2) Then
    If (MouseX < 100) Then
        ArrowXEndPoint = 0
    Else
        ArrowXEndPoint = MouseX - 75
    End If
ElseIf (MouseX > PicWidth / 2) Then
    If (MouseX > PicWidth - 100) Then
        ArrowXEndPoint = PicWidth
    Else
        ArrowXEndPoint = MouseX + 75
    End If
End If
End Function

Function PictureLocatedInCell(PictureName As String) As Collection ' find picture based on name
Dim PictureToChange As Shape: Set PictureToChange = Sheets("Input").Shapes(shapename)
Dim var As Collection
Set var = New Collection
var.add FindCellBasedOnTop(PictureToChange.Top, PictureToChange.Left)
var.add FindCellBasedOnLeft(PictureToChange.Top, PictureToChange.Left)
var.add PictureToChange.Left
var.add PictureToChange.Top
var.add PictureToChange.Width
var.add PictureToChange.Height
Set PictureLocatedInCell = var
End Function

Function ScreenDPI(bVert As Boolean) As Long
Static lDPI&(1), lDC&
If lDPI(0) = 0 Then
    lDC = GetDC(0)
    lDPI(0) = GetDeviceCaps(lDC, 88&)
    lDPI(1) = GetDeviceCaps(lDC, 90&)
    lDC = ReleaseDC(0, lDC)
End If
ScreenDPI = lDPI(Abs(bVert))
End Function

Function PTtoPX(Points As Single, bVert As Boolean) As Long
PTtoPX = Points * ScreenDPI(bVert) / 72
End Function

Function PXtoPT(Pixels As Long, bVert As Boolean) As Single
PXtoPT = Pixels / (ScreenDPI(bVert) / 72)
End Function

Sub GetRangeRect(ByVal rng As Range, ByRef rc As RECT)
Dim wnd As Window: Set wnd = rng.Parent.Parent.Windows(1)
With rng
    rc.Left = PTtoPX(.Left * wnd.Zoom / 100, 0) + wnd.PointsToScreenPixelsX(0)
    rc.Top = PTtoPX(.Top * wnd.Zoom / 100, 1) + wnd.PointsToScreenPixelsY(0)
    rc.Right = PTtoPX(.Width * wnd.Zoom / 100, 0) + rc.Left
    rc.Bottom = PTtoPX(.Height * wnd.Zoom / 100, 1) + rc.Top
End With
End Sub

Function SH03G13(shapename, CellX, CellY) As Collection
Dim wnd As Window
Dim var As Collection
Set var = New Collection
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    Dim AreaRng As Range: Set AreaRng = .Range(.Cells(CellX, CellY), .Cells(CellX, CellY))
    Dim rectang As Shape: Set rectang = .Shapes(shapename)
        'rectang.Height = AreaRng.Height
        'rectang.Width = AreaRng.Width
        'rectang.Top = AreaRng.Top
        'rectang.Left = AreaRng.Left
        DoEvents
    Dim Point As POINTAPI: GetCursorPos Point
    Dim rc As RECT: Call GetRangeRect(.Cells(CellX, CellY), rc)
    Dim ABCISSA As Long: ABCISSA = Point.Xcoord - rc.Left
    Dim ORDENAD As Long: ORDENAD = Point.Ycoord - rc.Top
End With

'MsgBox "x: " & ABCISSA & ", y: " & ORDENAD
Set wnd = Cells(CellX, CellY).Parent.Parent.Windows(1)
'Debug.Print "Zoom " & wnd.Zoom / 100
var.add PXtoPT(ABCISSA / (wnd.Zoom / 100), 0)
var.add PXtoPT(ORDENAD / (wnd.Zoom / 100), 0)

Set SH03G13 = var


End Function

Function FindCellBasedOnTop(Top, Left) As Integer
FindCellBasedOnTop = Round((Top - Sheets("Input").Rows("1:1").RowHeight) / Sheets("Input").Rows("2:2").RowHeight, 0) + 2
End Function

Function FindCellBasedOnLeft(Top, Left) As Integer
FindCellBasedOnLeft = Round((Left - Sheets("Input").Columns("A").ColumnWidth) / Sheets("Input").Columns("B").ColumnWidth, 0) + 1
End Function

Public Function shapename() As String
Dim ActiveShape As Shape
Dim ButtonName As String 'Get Name of Shape that initiated this macro
ButtonName = Application.Caller
'Set variable to active shape
Set ActiveShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ButtonName)
shapename = ActiveShape.name
End Function
```

If there is something which is unclear please tell me so.

Help will greatly be appreciated

Comment: what are `RECT` and `POINTAPI` types? And there are some subs/functions missing: `SaveFigure()` , `GetCursorPos()`, `ReleaseDC()`, `GetDeviceCaps()`, `GetDC()`. I guess there is some declaration missing...

Comment: I have updated the code, with the missing parts. Sorry for the inconveniencen..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are copy and pasting right after each other. If you have a break in between the kode will be able to run.

Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
Sleep 500
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select ' insert picture in sheet - this is where it fails

And the add this in the top of the sheet.

## If VBA7 Then ' Excel 2010 or later

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)
```

## Else ' Excel 2007 or earlier

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As Long)
```

## End If

BR